# How to view Description column in Gridview Microsoft test manager

Tags: test-management, mtm, grid

I need to view the description column in greadview in MTM, the issue is that when I go to Column options I can not find the description column, is there is something I should do? or is it not possible?
I need to copy paste test cases that have description from an excel sheet

[image]

As you can see in the above image, Description column is not available. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the "Description" named column under Column Options via List View or Grid View.  If the column is not listed under Column Options > Available Columns, then the column name does not exist as a default column name. Perhaps it is a custom column added by someone on your team. I would use Title & Step Actions columns to display any needed information in Grid View.

Custom fields can be displayed through web access but unfortunately these custom fields won’t be displayed in the MTM stand-alone Windows app.

You could submit this as a feature request to the Visual Studio product team at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio 
You can post your idea there so the others can up-vote your issue. 
If you submit this suggestion, you might post that link here which will benefit others who has the similar issue and can up-vote your issue so it gets more attention from the development team.

Currently, Grid View can only display:

- Test Case ID
- Test Case Title
- Test Case Step Actions
- Test Case Step Expected Result
- Test Case Reason
- Test Case State

Here's a screen shot of the grid view:

[image: tfs grid view example]